# Atoms in measurable spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In this post, by "separable measurable space" I mean the sigma algebra can be generated by a 
countable collection of sets. An algebra is a collection of sets that contains the empty set 
and is closed under complement and finite intersection.

**Definition** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space (not necessarily separable).
 For any $\omega \in \Omega$, let 
$$\mathcal F_\omega=\{ B\in \mathcal F:\omega\in B \}, A(\omega)=\bigcap_{B\in \mathcal F_\omega} B.$$

$A(\omega) $ is called the $\mathcal F$-atom containing $\omega$. $A(\omega) $ is not necessarily in $\mathcal F$. $A(\omega)$ is not the smallest measurable set containing $\omega$(which may be different from other definitions you have seen before).

Here is my question:

> > Let $\mathcal C$ be an algebra generating $\mathcal F$. For any $\omega \in \Omega$, 
> >     let $\mathcal C_\omega=\{ C\in \mathcal C:\omega\in C \}$, then do we have
> >     $$A(\omega)=\bigcap_{C\in \mathcal C_\omega} C.$$
> >     for general measurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$?
> >
> > If it fails for a nonseparable measurable space, does it still hold for a separable 
> >     measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$?

I have tried monotone class theorems for this problem but I find it hard to construct 
a "good" collection of sets. Every comment, solution or counterexample will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote 
$$
B(\omega) = \bigcap_{C\in \mathcal C_\omega} C. 
$$
Then for each $C\in \mathcal C$ we have  $C\cap B(\omega) \in\{\varnothing, B(\omega)\}$. Indeed, if $C\ni \omega$, then $C\supset B(\omega)$, otherwise $C^c\ni \omega$, so $C^c \supset B(\omega)$. Now consider the class
$$
\mathcal M = \big\{C\in \mathcal F: C\cap B(\omega) \in\{\varnothing, B(\omega)\}\big\}.
$$
We know that $\mathcal M\supset \mathcal C$, but also it is obviously a monotone class. Therefore, $\mathcal M = \mathcal F$, whence $B(\omega) = A(\omega)$, as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it seems that your argument only shows that if $A(\omega) \in \mathcal F$, then $B(\omega) = A(\omega)$. What if $A(\omega)$ is not in $\mathcal F$?

Comment: @TiWen, no. I never assume that $A(\omega)$ is in $\mathcal F$. Of course, in many cases, it isn't.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. You've showned that any set in $\mathcal F$ containing $\omega$ must also contain $B(\omega)$, which implies $B(\omega) \subseteq A(\omega)$.

Comment: @TiWen, exactly. And the opposite inclusion is obvious.